# ViewFlipper's onTouch event is NOT fired while its child Button's onClick event is

Tags: android, onclick

I've been struggling to find a solution in StackOverflow or elsewhere, but I couldn't find any direct post talking about this particular issue, maybe except for the possibly closest one that I can no longer find anymore. However, sorry in advance if this's simply because I overlook something or I'm just such a big noob.

Anyway, I'm trying to set OnTouchListener to a ViewFlipper (parents) and setOnClickListener to a Button (child) which fills the parent layout-wise. I wanted ViewFlipper's onTouch() event to be called first. Thought if ViewFlipper's onTouch() returned false, Button's onClick() was fired. However, only the Button's onClick() was called. Why? Is there any defined priority?

Alternatively, I could set an onTouchListener to the Button, since the Button has the 'match_parent' attribute, so touching this viewflipper was virtually the same as touching this button, even if I did so, it just makes Button's onClick() event unfired....

Below is my simplified Activity;

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, View.OnClickListener {
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnTest1);
    vf.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/button"
        layout="@layout/test" />
</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/testLinear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTest1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't grasp why ViewFlipper's onTouch event wasn't called first, but I found a way to kinda escape from this issue. We can set both onClickListener and onTouchListener to the button.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

As talked in the original post it prevents the onClick() event from happening, but whatsoever? If it's not called by android system, then we should call it manually.

```
@Override public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {

// walls of codes 

this.onClick(v);
```

I know I need some adjustments. I wouldn't call it 'Click' if user takes more than 0.5 second to get his finger off the screen.